# Sybase date comparison - Correct format?

Tags: sql, database, sybase, mybatis

I'm pretty new to Sybase and am writing a query to return results after a specified date, and also before a specified date. MM/DD/YYYY format

At the moment im doing..

```
SELECT * 
    From aTable
      WHERE afterDate >= 08/07/2013
        AND beforeDate <= 08/08/2013
```

I'm getting records back, but as I'm a Sybase newbie, I want to be sure Sybase is interpreting these dates correctly..

Their online doc is pretty bad for basic explanations on things like this!
Anyone able to confirm if what I have works, or does it need some formatting round the dates?

Comment: Something not mentioned in the answers so far is that since datefields often include time components, the best way to do date range queries is with "where yourfield >= startdate and yourfield < the day after enddate".  Notice the second comparison operator is less than, not less than or equal to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to convert the dates into DATETIME and tell sybase what the format is to be sure.
According to [this documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1540/doc/html/san1278453000116.html) the code for MM/DD/YYYY is 101, so something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM aTable
WHERE afterDate >= CONVERT(DATETIME,'08/07/2013',101)
      AND beforeDate <= CONVERT(DATETIME,'08/08/2013',101)
```

You can see the difference by running the following select statements:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'08/07/2013',101)  --MM/DD/YYYY (2013-08-07 00:00:00.000)
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,'08/07/2013',103)  --DD/MM/YYYY (2013-07-08 00:00:00.000)
```

Comment: Thankyou Ill have to try this out.  One thing I never mentioned was my query is called through MyBatis, so I'm wondering if even that will autoconvert to something Sybase accepts.

Comment: Thanks, this worked well.  Has helped me test correct records were being pulled back by MyBatis

Answer (score 7):

For any date-time field in sybase, instead of going through the convert function, there is a more direct approach.

```
SELECT * 
From aTable
  WHERE afterDate >= '2013-08-07'
    AND beforeDate <= '2013-08-08'
```

The date has to be in the form **'YYYY-MM-DD'**

If you want to add a time, it can be included along with the date. The date and the time have to be separated by a T.

Any date time field can be directly used using the format **'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS'**

Using the functions is too lengthy. Noone needs a bazooka to shoot a squirrel! :)

Answer (score 4):

```
CAST( '2000-10-31' AS DATE )
```

will  convert from text to date format....

I am assuming that your two  fields (afterDate  and beforeDate) are in Date format.

Your example would be:

```
SELECT * 
From aTable
  WHERE afterDate >= CAST( '08/07/2013' AS DATE )
    AND beforeDate <= CAST( '08/08/2013' AS DATE )
```

Also, usually (but not always) a date range is on the SAME field.  As I said, that is not true all the time and you may have a good reason for that.

Comment: Thanks I'll give this a go.  My query is written in a MyBatis xml file, so it'd be interesting to know if that handles autoconversion to something Sybase can handle for dates

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is to use the ANSI standard which does not require any conversion: yyyymmdd (you can also include hh:mm:ss) for instance:

DateField1 >= "20150101" and DateFile1 <= "20150102"

Answer (score 0):

You should decide which Input-Strings the user is going to use as parameter and then convert them and concatenate them like you want, unless it is Datetime it is not important which initial format it had, you can use it in a between-condition.

E. g. the user is from Europe and uses "DD.MM.YY" and "hh:mm" as an input parameter, I would convert and concatenate like this:

```
 WHERE dateCol between convert(DATETIME, 
                               convert(char(11), 
                                       convert(DATETIME, '01.06.14', 4), 16) || ' ' || '00:00', 8) 
    AND convert(DATETIME, 
                convert(char(11), 
                        convert(DATETIME, '01.07.14', 4), 16) || ' ' || '16:00', 8)
```